# Remove an item stored in an array based on a select

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, splice

I'm trying to remove an item stored inside an array base on the selected option, to understand better read this code:

`component.html`

```
<fnd-extended-select label="Tipo Prodotto:" [(ngModel)]="landingType" name="tipoprodotto">
    <fnd-option *ngFor="let p of agreementfilter?.landingPageTypes" [value]="p.id">{{p.description}}</fnd-option>
</fnd-extended-select>
```

`Component.ts`

```
  deleteMsg() {
    this.agreementfilter.landingPageTypes.splice(1, 1);
  }
```

Basically with this code when i press the button to delete the item only the **FIRST** object of the array is deleted.

**What I need**: Delete the item that ive selected from the array.

What kind of options do I have to solve the issue?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `this.agreementfilter.landingPageTypes.splice(here pass index of your element, 1);` provide index of selected item.

Comment: findIndex of your selected "landingType"  in the array after then splice it out as you do only the first element at the moment

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: My problem is that I dont know how to pass the index of the array to the button, I tried with "let i = index" in the ngFor but in the component.ts it says its undefined since index is created and dies inside the *ngFor

Comment: @Synoon That might work, can you post an example on how to use that? Im kinda new to Angular and ive never used that :)

Comment: @FrancescoGiberti which event occurs to delete the array element ?

Comment: @BhavyaSanchaniya  (click)="deleteMsg()"  its just a simple button that on click delete the item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right solution was provided by @Nenad Radak in the comments of his answer.

Ive stored the value in my component and then called it again on the event of the button.

code:

temporary:string;

```
<fnd-extended-select label="Tipo Prodotto:" [(ngModel)]="landingType" name="tipoprodotto">
  <fnd-option *ngFor="let p of agreementfilter?.landingPageTypes; let i = index" (click)="tempor(i)" [value]="p.id">{{p.description}}</fnd-option>
</fnd-extended-select>


 tempor(index){debugger;
   this.temporary= index
 }
  deleteMsg() {

    this.agreementfilter.landingPageTypes.splice(this.temporary, 1);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

component.html

```
<fnd-extended-select label="Tipo Prodotto:" [(ngModel)]="landingType" 
 name="tipoprodotto">
<fnd-option *ngFor="let p of agreementfilter?.landingPageTypes; let i = index" 
  [value]="i">{{p.description}}</fnd-option></fnd-extended-select> <button (click)="deleteMsg(landingType)"></button>
```

component.ts

```
 landingType;

  public deleteMsg(id: number) {
    // finds index of item to be deleted and then deletes the item from the array
    this.landingPageTypes.splice(id, 1);

    // output array to console with item deleted
    console.log('landingPageTypes: ', this.landingPageTypes);
  }

public change(id) {
  // change select and index store in variable
  this.landingType = id;
  console.log(id);
}
```

check out example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m9pygg)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it like this,add click event and pass index as parameter

Component.html

```
 <fnd-extended-select label="Tipo Prodotto:" [(ngModel)]="landingType" 
     name="tipoprodotto">
    <fnd-option *ngFor="let p of agreementfilter?.landingPageTypes; let i = index" 
      [value]="p.id" (click)="deleteMsg(i)">{{p.description}}</fnd-option>
  </fnd-extended-select>
```

Component.ts

```
 deleteMsg(index) {

   this.agreementfilter.landingPageTypes.splice(this.agreementfilter.landingPageTypes.indexof(index), 1);
}
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion but (click)="deleteMsg(i)"   is not on the <fnd-option> but on another button so i cant pass the index value to the other component

Comment: we had misunderstanding then :)

Comment: yep, if the event was on the input it would have been so easy to do but sadly its located on a button :(

Comment: Maybe you can take index from click on option,retrieve it in ts in file and store it in new variable which can be then send to button?

Comment: @NenadRadak in angular select option (click) event working ?

Comment: Yes you can add (click)="yourFunc()" and pass parameter.On clicked option you will get value.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the item by finding its index. 
suppose the item you want to delete is the item you selected (which is set to model)- 'landingType'

```
      deleteMsg() {
        this.agreementfilter.landingPageTypes.splice(this.agreementfilter.landingPageTypes.indexOf(landingType), 1);
}
```

Try this :

```
    var months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
      console.log(months);
    // expected output: Array ['Jan','March', 'April', 'June']

     console.log(months);
     months.splice(months.indexOf('April'), 1);
   // expected output: Array ['Jan','March', 'June']
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, ive tried this but sadly it doesnt delete the item of the array.

There is also an error in the console: this.agreementfilter.landingPageTypes.indexof is not a function

Comment: Hey, Sorry there was spelling mistake in function name - try using indexOf() instaed of indexof().

Comment: Dont worry,  this still doesnt work since it delete the first item of the array and not the selected one :(

Comment: It must work because its a javascript concept, there might be errors in my code but the logic behind the code is to get index of item and remove that item from the list.

Answer (score 0):

In your delete message function pass in the ID of the item you want to delete, then look up the index of that item in the array using findIndex. Once you have the index you can use splice to delete the entry at that index.

Ive put together this Stackblitz as an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-icpmqo

```
public deleteMsg(id: number) {
    this.landingPageTypes.splice(this.landingPageTypes.findIndex((page) => page.id === id), 1);
}
```